# Simple version/history on ndb/Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, versioning, app-engine-ndb

I am looking to create a system for tracking versions (history) of content of ndb.Models/Expandos on Google App Engine (Python).

The content can be relatively lengthy and there may be many versions, but diffs between versions may be quite small. I expect others have done something like this and I would like to know how they went about it and what principles may guide the design & development.

It is not known at the time of deployment what the attributes of the data models would be (e.g. "title", "content", "body", "dated", etc.), but the types are known (dates, text, etc).

My initial thought is to have the arranged something like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Version(ndb.Expando):
  version_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  # dated, etc.
  # data properties are not known in advance, hence Expando

 class MyDoc(ndb.Model):
   head     = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Version)

   instance = ndb.kind=Property(kind=Version, repeated=True)
   # ^^^ may be a StructuredProperty?
```

The overview of the algorithms is:

#### Saving

Every time a user saves a document, put all the latest data into a new `Version` and point `head` to that instance.

At that point, or some time after, go through old versions and change full saves to diffs (to save on space) with e.g. [diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/). I would expect one full save per hour, day or some set time - or some set number of diffs.

#### Loading

Loading `head` is trivial.

Older versions would be marked as a full save or a diff, and depending on which the data may be returned directly or compiled from the diff.

#### Thoughts?

I am sure others have tackled this problem, and I would love to know what ideas and implementations are out there about it. Obviously, there are full version control systems such as Git, Mercurial and Subversion and CVS - but those are both overkill for the intended purpose and would not work on Google App Engine.

Comment: Have you considered simply using the model from something like Git and adapting it to your own purposes?

Comment: I'm curious as to whether you found a solution to this, I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

- You'll want a monotonically increasing ID for the versions, so you can do range queries of Version entities.  This probably means you'll want all historical data in the same entity group as the document, and keep the latest version ID on the document entity or in a separate entity in the same group.  If you want a system-wide monotonically increasing ID (such as to associate or order changes made to multiple entities in different groups), you'll want to look into sharded counters and cross-group transactions.
- If space is enough of a concern that you'll be storing diffs, I don't see why you'd reduce full versions to diffs with a background job, and not just on update.  If space is not a big concern and a major feature is to be able to diff two arbitrary versions, then it might just be easier to store full data, so the cost of a diff isn't proportional to the number of intermediate versions (or all versions, if your diff is between historical versions).  Assuming you don't want to perform queries on properties of past versions, you could save space by serializing the old entity in a compact form, and storing it in a non-indexed blob property.  (I assume this is how you'd store each diff anyway, if you used diffs?)  You could also keep full docs at milestones every n revisions, so a diff between two historical versions requires at most 2n versions to calculate.
- From your description it sounds like you'd prefer MyDoc to be a reference to a Version entity, which would contain the headmost data.  Maybe it'd be easier for MyDoc to contain the headmost data (and have its properties indexed with MyDoc keys, etc.), and an update just creates the Version with the previous data (diff or full).
- Don't forget to accommodate deletes.  Maybe MyDoc goes away (so it doesn't show up in key and property queries), and the most recent Version for the parent path contains the full last known document.

(This is just off the top of my head.  I put a little thought into this for a CMS I work on, but I haven't built it.)

Comment: Many version control systems don't have monotonically increasing IDs. And you can't use sharded counters to generate a monotonically increasing ID.